# Python decorator: TypeError: function takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to test the utility of decorators in Python. When I write the following codes, there is an error:

```
TypeError: fizz_buzz_or_number() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I first define a function `log_calls(fn)` as

```
def log_calls(fn):
    ''' Wraps fn in a function named "inner" that writes
    the arguments and return value to logfile.log '''
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        # Call the function with the received arguments and
        # keyword arguments, storing the return value
        out = fn(args, kwargs)

        # Write a line with the function name, its
        # arguments, and its return value to the log file
        with open('logfile.log', 'a') as logfile:
            logfile.write(
               '%s called with args %s and kwargs %s, returning %s\n' %
                (fn.__name__,  args, kwargs, out))

        # Return the return value
        return out
    return inner
```

After that, I use log_calls to decorate another function as:

```
@log_calls
def fizz_buzz_or_number(i):
    ''' Return "fizz" if i is divisible by 3, "buzz" if by
        5, and "fizzbuzz" if both; otherwise, return i. '''
    if i % 15 == 0:
        return 'fizzbuzz'
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        return 'fizz'
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        return 'buzz'
    else:
        return i
```

When I run the following code

```
for i in range(1, 31):
    print(fizz_buzz_or_number(i))
```

The error `TypeError: fizz_buzz_or_number() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` comes.

I don't know what is wrong with this decorator, and how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing in 2 arguments to your decorated function here:

```
out = fn(args, kwargs)
```

If you wanted to apply the `args` tuple and `kwargs` dictionary as variable arguments, echo the function signature syntax, so use `*` and `**` again:

```
out = fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

See the [*Call* expressions reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax `*expression` appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from these iterables are treated as if they were additional positional arguments.
>
> [...]
>
> If the syntax `**expression` appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to a mapping, the contents of which are treated as additional keyword arguments.

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried again according to your suggestion, it works now.  Thanks a lot.